# Memory Handling Issues

Tags: c++, oop

I started learning C++ about 1-2 days and I came here from Java.
But I met one problem when deleting an object.
The problem comes when I try to create new object after deleting the old one.
I have class "Player" which stores its position, angle, motion and color in RGB format.
Here is the code:

```
class Player {
    public:
        float posX, posY, motionX, motionY, angle, r, g, b;
        Player (float, float);
        ~Player() {}; 

        void draw() {
            < GLCode goes here.. >
        }
};

Player::Player(float x, float y) {
    posX = x;
    posY = y;
    cout << "created a player object!\n";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv);
void redraw(void);
void update(void);

//Players List
std::vector<Player*> data;

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
     switch (key) {
        case VK_ESCAPE:
            if (data.size() > 0) {
                Player *p =  data[data.size()-1];
                delete p;
                p = NULL;
                data.pop_back();
                cout << data.size() << endl;
            }
         break;

        case VK_SPACE:
            Player* p = new Player(200, 200);
            data.push_back(p);
         break;
     }
 }

void redraw(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    for (UINT i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        Player* pr = data[i];
        if (pr)
            pr->draw();
    }

    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void update(int v) {
    glutTimerFunc(20, update, 0);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void initGL(int argc, char **argv) {
    < GLCode goes here.. >
}

void initGameLogic(void) {
    // Here I am creating two player objects, one is red color and one is green
    Player* p = new Player(300, 200);
    p->r = 0;
    p->g = 1;
    p->b = 0;
    data.push_back(p);
    p = new Player(400, 200);
    p->r = 1;
    p->g = 0;
    p->b = 0;
    data.push_back(p);
}

void initGameLoop(void) {
    < GLCode goes here.. >
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    initGL(argc, argv);
    initGameLogic();
    initGameLoop();
}
```

So the problem is that when I press ESC (and delete the last player) and press SPACE after this the program creates new player object for me but it somehow (though I certainly deleted the old player object) gets the GREEN (old player's color) color however the standard color is black. If I press it again it creates new player and now with BLACK color. 
So if I delete all the players and then create them one right after another - first two comes in green and red colors what means that the program does not clean object variables. I can store float pointers in class, allocate memory to them at the initialization and then delete it in destructor but then my destructor method should be just giant, because I would need to delete all vars stored in my object.
So whats wrong with my code?

Is it memory-leak or maybe it is just variable-initialization problem when I should reset all variables in the constructor?

And yep, sorry for my bad English.

**EDIT**: Solved, thanks to Ivan Ishchenko, Vlad from Moscow and Mohammad Ali Baydoun.
Btw, just replacing array's type with player object (not a pointer) as suggested Mohammad Ali Baydoun worked for me.

Comment: The problem is that you're misusing pointers and memory allocation. `std::vector<Player>` would give you better results. No need to do manual allocation and deletion then.

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun Though I completely agree the dynamic memory usage like that exhibited here is both error prone to errors and unnecessary in modern C++, where specifically is it *"the problem"* in the OP's code?

Comment: @WhozCraig I'd say uninitialized variables, but the answers already sum it up :s

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun exactly (and I up-voted them both). dynamic usage has nothing to do with the real problem, and make no mistake: I **completely agree** with you this is not anywhere close to a "correct" design. it just isn't the problem causing the behavior the OP is seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting color for 2 first players and never for new ones. So new players color variables are uninitialized and could store anything they want. Consider to initialize them with BLACK at Player constructor.

Comment: So it is just variable-initialization problem? Just I wonder why it stores the old color even after deleting my object. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, it is. It seem new Player just happens to occur at the same memory as an old one.

Comment: By chance, new object was created exactly on top of where the old object was allocated.

Comment: @ZnW As Mohammad stated in general comment, there is a better design for doing what you're trying. Proper initialization is part of that, if you're interested.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, I have done this part already, look at the "EDIT" section. Worked for me pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

Your constructor does not initialize variables r, g, b. So if an object created with the operator new is value initialized then variables r, g, b have arbitrary values.

Comment: +1 Note: its not just `operator new` created objects; the same problem would happen in non-dynamic usage as well. There is no value-initialization of the rgb members in the only non-copy-ctor of the class. The OP needs to learn how to properly use an initializer list.